# Integration over a cube the correct way?

Tags: calculus, volume

Suppose we have a cube, and I want to integrate the function $f(x,y,z)$ over it where $x,y,z$ are the variable in given three dimensions. Assuming cube's center is at a distance of $d$ from the point of reference, and the side of cube as $2r$, I want to know how should I perform the integration this way:
$$\int_{d-r}^{d+r}\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-r}^{r} f(x,y,z) dx ~dy ~dz$$ or this way:
$$\int_{d-r}^{d+r}\int_{-r}^{r}\int_{-\sqrt{2}r}^{\sqrt{2}r} f(x,y,z) dx ~dy ~dz$$

Which way is correct and why?

Comment: Is $d$ not too unprecise to determine the position of the cube? This leaves a sphere around the origin as position of the center.

Comment: @mvw Actually I get the logic of a surface integral over a square extended over to volume for surface integral over a square. The square with length $2r$ and distance of center of square is $d$ from the reference. The surface integral is given by:$$\int_{d-r}^{d+r}\int_{-r}^{r}f(x,y) dx~ dy$$, am I wrong?

Comment: Just make sure your integration variables cover all the values within the cube. Is $x \in [-r, r], y \in [d-r, d+r]$? Here the center is at $(0, d)$. Then it is fine.

Comment: Your first integral assumes the center at $(0, 0, d)$. Side lengths are $2r$. The second integral has the same center, but sides $2\sqrt{2}r\times 2r\times 2r$.